# How to calculate an AVG of a column without zeros? using WITH twice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this query:

```
with T1 as (
   SELECT [CaseNum]
  ,CreationDate
  ,[IsPanic]
  ,ISNULL(LAG(CreationDate,1)OVER(PARTITION BY [CaseNum] ORDER BY CreationDate),CreationDate) PreviousDate
 FROM [EmergencyRoomMetrics].[dbo].[ERSystem_RequestsResults_LAB]
 where TestDescr like '%Potassium%'
 and CreationDate >= dateadd(day, -365, getdate())

  )


SELECT CaseNum,
   CreationDate,
   IsPanic,
   PreviousDate,
   DATEDIFF(minute,PreviousDate,CreationDate) as LapsedSeconds
  
   From T1
```

It works great and gives me the table I want to see but how can I calculate the AVG of the LapsedSeconds column without zero values?

the LapsedSeconds looks like this:

```
    LapsedSeconds
----------------------------
0
0
0
34
34
0
89
67
```

I've tried:

```
 with T1 as (
   SELECT [CaseNum]
  ,CreationDate
  ,[IsPanic]
  ,ISNULL(LAG(CreationDate,1)OVER(PARTITION BY [CaseNum] ORDER BY CreationDate),CreationDate) PreviousDate
 FROM [EmergencyRoomMetrics].[dbo].[ERSystem_RequestsResults_LAB]
 where TestDescr like '%Potassium%'
 and CreationDate >= dateadd(day, -365, getdate())

  ),

T2 as(
SELECT CaseNum,
   CreationDate,
   IsPanic,
   PreviousDate,
   DATEDIFF(minute,PreviousDate,CreationDate) as LapsedSeconds
  
   From T1
    )
 SELECT AVG(NULLIF(LapsedSeconds,0) as AVGE
FROM T2
```

and it doesnt work. it says: Incorrect syntax near 'T2'. (at the end)

So how can I calculate the AVG of the LapsedSeconds column without zeros?

Comment: *"but I cant do WITH twice..."* are you, perhaps, trying to do `WITH CTE1 AS (...), WITH CTE2 AS ...`? You only need the `WITH` at the very start; the syntax is `WITH CTE1 AS (...), CTE2 AS ...` You didn't actually include your attempt that isn't working, nor the error; don't make us guess here.

Comment: Hey Larnu, check my update. I've tried like you said and it did not work can you spot my error?

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?

Comment: look at the code above. it says: Incorrect syntax near 'T2'.

Comment: `AVG(NULLIF(LapsedSeconds,0)` You are missing a right paranthesis.

Comment: you were right! the right parenthesis was missing! now it worked! thanks a lot for your help! sorry if my comments were disrespectful

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I saw I was missing a parenthesis at the end so the full answer is:

```
 with T1 as (
 SELECT [CaseNum]
,CreationDate
,[IsPanic]
,ISNULL(LAG(CreationDate,1)OVER(PARTITION BY [CaseNum] ORDER BY 
CreationDate),CreationDate) PreviousDate
FROM [EmergencyRoomMetrics].[dbo].[ERSystem_RequestsResults_LAB]
where TestDescr like '%Potassium%'
and CreationDate >= dateadd(day, -365, getdate())

),

T2 as(
SELECT CaseNum,
CreationDate,
IsPanic,
PreviousDate,
DATEDIFF(minute,PreviousDate,CreationDate) as LapsedSeconds

From T1
 )
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(LapsedSeconds,0)) as AVGE
FROM T2

AVGE
-------
109
```

Thank to everyone who helped!